# How can I delete xfce4 if I deleted crouton?

Tags: xfce, chromebook

I downloaded xfce on my Chromebook, but my graphics driver isn't updated enough so I cant do a lot of the things I wanted to, and I wasn't successful at updating it so I am currently trying to delete xfce and get kde or some other version, but I deleted crouton, so when I type in the command to delete it, It doesn't work. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of Chromebooks is that you can do a clean reset of the device if you did something wrong to it, and lose nothing.

But from what you have written, I think you are running Crouton rather than a full Linux install - which I would say from experience does not usually result in a very stable computer.

If you wish to use Ubuntu full time on your Chromebook, I recommend installing Ubuntu onto the hard-drive directly.